# How to correctly apply php PDO to Laravel

Tags: php

As the search result of mine, Laravel uses PDO to process database queries by default, and there is no need to escape any queries as what `mysql_real_escape_string()` does when using PDO.
`mysql_real_escape_string()` converts `\r` to `\\r`, and this is what I need because I don't want a carriage return character appears in username.
But, when I try this:

```
$name="\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r";
$user = User::where("username","=",$input)->first();
$user->name=$name;
$user->save();
echo "<p>".$user["name"]."</p>";
```

The output html code is like this:

```
<p>








</p>
```

Does PDO use another method to handle `\r`?
Or Laravel isn't using PDO to handle this query?
What's the best way I can do to achieve my need?

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: @user2864740 Beecause I'm using PHP5.5, I can't test it on my PC, all based on googled result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise is wrong: *A valid "_escape_string" does **not** change the content of the data*, only the encoding in/for the specific context.

If newlines (or other odd characters) are not desired then apply a *business rule* guard or filter to the data from the user.

(Also, client-side escaping might not even be used internally by PDO.)

Comment: And I also want to know is Laravel really using PDO or I need more code to avoid sql injection?

Comment: @Kai As long as user data is only used in the *data-position* of the methods (as done in the question) then it is free from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), although business rules can be trivially violated (e.g. the `\n` in this case). Laravel does indeed use PDO internally. See [Laravel queries](http://laravel.com/docs/queries).

Comment: @Kai Glad it is :) Also, remember to correctly escape/encode the data when it is used (in HTML). In the post, if the name was something like "<script>..</script>" then you'd have HTML/script injection introduced by the raw echo!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace some characters in your data, it should not matter what database layer you are using.

Just replace whatever characters you want with appropriate PHP function. That's all